# Security concerns of passing around a Java Connection to multiple public functions

Tags: java, sql, security

given the following function:

```
public void foo(Connection conn)  
{  
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("Select a from table");  
    statement.execute();
}
```

with a `Connection` object that was instantiated elsewhere (Whether external or internal to the application does not matter).  Are there are any security issues that can arise by allowing functions in the API of an application to accept a non-validated `Connection`?  For example, can a non-validated connection trick my application into running malicious queries?

Comment: any example of a non-validated connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible that the `Connection` object can run malicious queries.

And: No, I don't know a way to prevent this as the `Connection` (or a `DataSource`) is needed by the code that executes queries.

Some type of this is used e.g. for connection pools. From connection pools you get a `Connection` object where e.g. the `open()` and `close()` methods do not work as intended (as the pool wants to close the connection if needed). And so a connection pool could also override other methods (as `Connection` is only an interface).

Comment: can you provide me an example (theoretical or practical) of how it would execute arbitrary functions?

Comment: Simply by acting as proxy the `Connection` in your application has nothing to do with a real `Connection` to the database. The proxy can then do anything it wants.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, whatever is injecting that Connection object already has a reference to the connection object.  It could run malicious queries on its own, with or without your code.